# Can't Make Site Appear Correctly In Different Browsers

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am extremely new to programming and I am attempting to code a website currently.  I've spent about 5 hours in the last 2 days just trying to get things to line up correctly on various browsers and I'm having a few issues.  First, let me say that I'm sorry if this question has been answered somewhere before.  I've looked at a lot of solutions to problems similar to mine and nothing has completely worked for me, so please be patient.  First, I have the problem of things appearing in random places on different browsers.  When I attempt to remedy this in the CSS, I spawn new problems in other browers.  Secondly, as the browser window changes size, all the elements on the page start moving around and overlapping instead of just hiding outside of the window.  My third issue I'm having (sort of) is that my code looks terrible.  I'm not sure why some elements have to have -4.5% margins to line up with other elements that need -5% margins; and I'm not sure why I'm having to put negative margins on certain elements to begin with!  Thank you in advance for all of your help and preventing me from going postal.

Josh

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Horton Computer Solutions Home</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="site_title", style="float:left">

  <span class="titleleft">Horton</span>|<span class="titleright">Computer Solutions</span>
</div>
            <div id="title_bar", style="float:right">
                <ul>
                    <pre><a href="#">Home</a>    <a href="#">About Us</a>    <a href="#">Services</a>    <a href="#">Guarantee</a>    <a href="#">Blog</a>    <a href="#">Contact</a></pre>
                </ul>
                <br style="clear:both"/>
            </div>
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="subContent1">
    </div>
    <div id="subContent2">
    </div>
    <div id="subContent3">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
/* language: css */
BODY
{
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #062134;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 0 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
A
{
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
DIV#title_bar UL A
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
DIV#title_bar UL A:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
DIV#title_bar UL A:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
DIV#site_title
{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: -4.5% 0 0 6.9%;
}
DIV#title_bar
{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -5% auto auto 40%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
DIV#contentBox
{
    background-color: #1468A8;
    border-style: none;
    width: 338px;
    height: 185px;
    padding: 19px;
}
#site_title .titleleft
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#site_title .titleright
{
    color: #46C8FF;
}
DIV#mainContent
{
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    /*+box-sizing:border-box;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 950px;
    height: 1135px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 10% 6%;
    padding: 15px;
}
DIV#subContent1
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 292px;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 440px 0 0;
}
DIV#subContent2
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 292px;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: -255px 0 0 313px;
}
DIV#subContent3
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 292px;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: -255px 0 0 626px;
}
#site_title .floatleft
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#title_bar .floatright
{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dankpiff/kDAPu/

So What specific elements are appearing out of place from what you where it 'should' be?

Comment: You might try removing position:absolute from the body tag.  Never seen that before.

Comment: The "title_bar" is supposed to be slightly higher inline with the "site_title", but the real issues show up in Chrome.  The site is completely mangled.  I've poked around on various forums and this seems to be a common issues for people like me that don't know what they're doing, but none of the suggestions help me.  Also, the absolute tag on the body was an attempt to fix the issues and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism, but it has been reasonably answered by 3 different people.

Answer (score 2):

Your code semantic are all over the shop, it's not surprising you are having issues and before trying to resolve any cross browser issue you must ensure your code validates (http://validator.w3.org/)

First I would say drop the complex doctype and use HTML5 one, it's strict and works everywhere. Always stay away from transitional doctype if you can help it.

So

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

When setting multiple attribute on an element you don't need commas so

```
<div id="title_bar", style="float:right">
```

becomes

```
<div id="title_bar" style="float:right">
```

Avoid style attributes, here most of your elements have ids you can style them from your style sheet (http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

90% of the time you don't need clear:both, just having overflow:hidden on the container element is good enough to clear floated children.

UL element MUST contains LI element

```
<ul>
    <pre><a href="#">Home</a>....</pre>
</ul>
```

becomes

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

When inserting link tags for CSS unless you serve multiple files for various devices you don't need the media="screen" part, that's the default value if the attribute is not set.

When referencing tags in your CSS files don't use uppercase, it's rather old fashion and not really used (also some might argue they prefer it you won't see any "famous" developer using them)

now for your styling issue your BR style="clear:both" is inside the menu element, when it should be after in order to clear both title and menu (also like said just have a wrapper around them and have overflow:hidden in CSS, it will also separate your header from your content better)

float:left + position:relative kind of clash. Also if you set position:relative no need to set top:0 and left:0 that's where the element would be in a position:relative situation.

I think that should, at least, aim you into the right direction or well help somehow :)

Comment: I made most of the changes you suggested but I have a couple problems.  First if I add the <li> tags all of the links become vertically listed and won't line up horizontally.  Second, not putting the br style="clear:both" in the wrong place was causing all my issues with having to use negative margins; but if I remove the float styles entirely my page alignment because even worse.  Lastly, when you say don't reference tags in CSS with uppercase, do you mean  typing "DIV"?  If so, why?  Is it just less aesthetically pleasing or can it actually cause problems?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: +1 for helping a out, while explaining the process behind the changes to further their own development.

Comment: There is no issue with using upper case tags, as far as I know, but it's just sort of a good standard (you can even write HTML like that but it's very rare to see even if popular back in the days)

The li don't align because their default behaviour is to be display:block, so you need to float them. Have overflow:hidden on the ul and float the ul itself (I assume you want it on the right)

I would recommend restarting your CSS file as at the moment it's a bit messy due the normal process of trials and errors. It will give you a cleaner start and a fresher look at your problems.

Comment: Thank you man I really appreciate your suggestions.  I'm going to rewrite the css and see what happens, then I'll report back.  I'd upvote you but I don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Comments like

```
<!-- language: css -->
```

are not allowed in css files. Only use

```
/* language: css */
```

to comment.

Comment: No, because you didn't solve anything.  You just told me to change how I said what language it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to work the same on all the browsers. Scrap your styles and start with a reset style sheet: (google: reset stylesheet, first link).

The formatting will more than likely be the same on all browsers (except for the individual browser limitations, ie: no css3 on ie6,7,etc). I think you'll find it easier to format once the browser style differences have been eliminated.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

solution for your second question

```
  <body>
   <center>
     //do all here
  </center>
 </body>
```

Comment: I'll give that a try in my rewrite.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: The <center> element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake was here, remove the comma after id end

```
    <div id="title_bar" style="float:right">
```

check this one http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/aXaYg/2/

Comment: One of my many mistakes*

Comment: check your mistakes and output file was below link                      http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/aXaYg/1/

Comment: Please stop repeatedly rolling back your revisions.

Comment: What does "repeatedly rolling back your revisions" mean?

Comment: sorry i don't know how to use it ?,please provide some video examples for how to use this site menus and etc.